# Primality test for $N=2\cdot 3^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you provide proof or counterexample for the following claim:

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot \left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}\right)$ . Let $N=2\cdot 3^n-1$ such that  $n>2$  . Let $S_i=P_3(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0$ equal to the modular $P_6(P_{3}(4)) \phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} N$ . Then , $N$ is prime iff $S_{n-2} \equiv 2 \pmod{N}$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLszW25vKzNdIyjsvTNbTmCrb1zU_RMNIqyM9JzkhNqizOSC3TMNMx1EERMAYKGGlq6vhpWnMllxTZAjWWZ2TmpGoAOTa2ebpGOljNAWkL1jcC6wOq1LY1BOrPTNMItrU10ikoyswr0VACUrmpSpowbnJ-bkF-cWYJUEjTGgCN5zR9&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

[OEIS sequence of exponents $n$ for wich $N$ is prime](https://oeis.org/A003307)

I was searching for counterexample using the following PARI/GP code :

```
CE231(lb,ub)=
{
for(n=lb,ub,
N=2*3^n-1;
S=Mod(2*polchebyshev(6,1,polchebyshev(3,1,2)),N);
ctr=1;
while(ctr<=n-2,
S=Mod(2*polchebyshev(3,1,S/2),N);
ctr+=1);
if(S==2 && !ispseudoprime(N),print(n)))
}
```

I have verified this claim for all $n$ up to $7000$ .

Comment: FYI, $P_3(x) \equiv x^3 - 3x$.